# Clearing the layout cache in a Rails application

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My `application.html.slim` template looks like this conceptually:

```
/ some stuff
= header()
/ more stuff
= yield
/ more stuff
= footer()
```

Now `header()` and `footer()` are loaded from an external source and they are language-specific.

I have introduced a language-change mechanism (based on the URL) so the `header` and the `footer` will be loaded from a different source as soon as the language is changed.

My Problem:

- I start up the server
- I load `http://myserver.dev/en`
- The content as well as the header is shown in english --> **OK**
- I load `http://myserver.dev/de`
- Now the header is still in english while the content is in german --> **Not OK**
- Now the header and the footer won't change until i restart the server again.

So how can I clear the layout cache, so that the `footer` and `header` are re-loaded.

I tried the following (to no avail):

- Manually removing the cache files from disk (they still seem to be in memory)
- Adding the following setting in my `application.rb`

  ```
  config.action_view.cache_template_loading = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  ```
- Invoking `Rails.cache.clear` in *every request*
- Attempting to expire the individual partial: `expire_fragment('external/_header.html.slim')` or `expire_fragment(%r{external})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem thanks to @gabrimac's post:

So when I define a special cache key in the view like so:

```
- cache("language_dependant_partial") do 
  = ApplicationHelper::footer()
```

then I can invalidate the cache by using this specific identifier:

```
before_filter :clear_cache

def clear_cache

  # TODO: This currently clear's the cache on every request
  expire_fragment('language_dependant_partial')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I avoided this situation using fragment cache and creating a block cache for each language.

In the views define the block you will change the language with:

```
<% cache("block_1_#{I18n.locale}") do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the sense of caching when it expires for changed language (every request)? Unless `change_language` is smart and knows somehow user current and previous language.

Comment: Thanks @gabrimac I was able to fix the problem now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26833602/784318